# Dynamic push to array by length

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I am having an issue with the below code.
I have an array like this:

```
let length = 2;
let data1 = ['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3'];
let data2 = []
```

I want to push `data2` with the `data1` value by length. The expectation I want is this:

```
data2 = ['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3', 'Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3'];
```

Any suggestions how I can dynamically push to an array?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
let length = 2;
let data1 = ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3"];
let data2 = [];

data2 = Array.from({ length }, () => data1).flat();
console.log(data2);
```